# "Sublime Text 2" like scrolling with javascript / jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

i'm trying to implement a Sublime 2 like scrolling bar with code preview in javascript / jquery.

[image]

Are there any plugins or code snippets out there which are trying to achieve the same?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use this jQuery plugin: http://larsjung.de/fracs/ and there is also a demo (exactly what you are looking for: http://larsjung.de/fracs/demo).

Answer (score 9):

I created a new project to do exactly this. It copies the content into an iframe and scales it down using css. So no canvas, no CORS issues and dimensions are correct.
https://github.com/demux/sublime-scroll/

Comment: genus, but how can i apply it on my site ??

Comment: @demux Your demo link on the github page is broken :) can you fix?

Comment: @VolcovMeter I doubt that I'll get to it soon, but it pretty much looks like this... https://github.com/demux/react-minimap

Comment: Awesome - Thanks!!